# custom UIPickerView - limit user to spinning one wheel at a time

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I have a custom `UIPickerView` with three components that are dependent on one another (i.e., the second one shows values depending on what has been selected in the first one and the third is dependent on the first and second). I am getting the values that are shown in the `UIPickerView` out of an `NSDictionary`.

Everything works nicely, except, when I spin two of the components at the same time, the app sometimes crashes (no time to reload data).  This is what my `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent` looks like:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    NSLog(@"Selecting row %d component %d", row, component);

    // When A is changed, we need to reload B and C
    if (component == 0) {

        [pickerView reloadComponent:1];
        [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];

        // need to reload the C after reloading B
        [self pickerView:pickerView didSelectRow:0 inComponent:1];

    }
    else if (component == 1) {
        [pickerView reloadComponent:2];
        [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:2 animated:YES];
    }
    [self updateSelection];
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the user from spinning more than one component of the picker at a time to prevent a crash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good holy Jesus you call `didSelectRow:component:` recursively!

I know that the way you handle parameters prevents it from going more than two levels deep, but still, don't do that. Ever.

There's no way to prevent the user from spinning more than one component at a time. It is the joy of multitouch and iOS to set everything in motion and watch it all settle down into a consistent state. And because the spinner components take time to settle, the user can set them all atwitter using just one finger. You must learn to write your code accordingly.

In this case, you want to delete all calls to `didSelectRow:component:` from within itself - it is to be called by the system *only*. You're on the right track with your use of `reloadComponent:`, it's just that you're not reloading enough of them:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"Selecting row %d component %d", row, component);

    [self updateSelection];

    // When A is changed, we need to reload B and C
    if (component == 0) {
        [pickerView reloadComponent:1];
        [pickerView reloadComponent:2];
    } else if (component == 1) {
        [pickerView reloadComponent:2];
    }
}
```

I don't know what your `updateSelection` does - presumably it sets the data model based on the value of `pickerView`. This is fine - but it needs to happen at the top of your method, so that when whichever of your `titleForRow` or `viewForRow` is called, it has the proper data to choose from. Also, from within any of those three (`update`,`titleFor`, `viewFor`) do ***not*** assert values into the picker! Just read from it.

I think this is a good starting point for you, but you will have to tweak things a little here and there as you get closer to your goal. I think you will find that the key to Pickers is that they only assert `didSelectRow:component:` when one of the component spinner things settles down on a value, and they're really good about continuing to spin if you reload them. Give this a shot and see if you can make some progress, send word back if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you SO much!- I pulled all of the didSelectRows out of my code and am using reloadComponents instead...  Still getting crashes when the view does not match what I have in my model (which is a NSDictionary of NSDictionarys of NSArrays, component 0 being the keys of the NSDictionary, component 1 being the keys of the sub-NSDictionaries and component 2 being the NSArray found under the key in component 1).  One thing about your example is I need updateSelection to come after the components are reloaded or I will not get a correct value for what is in the third component.

Comment: got it working with lots of tweaks!  The other addition I added to what you have above is adding [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES] after reloading component 1 and [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:2 animated:YES] after reloading component 2.  VERY grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Spinning two wheels at a time means you have multi-touch enabled, right?
So, a possibility, may be to just disable multi-touch and limit the user to touching and affecting only one wheel in the UIPickerView.

Here's a [link](http://joshhighland.com/blog/2009/09/17/uipickerview-spinning-multiple-components/) that might help.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me out!  Unfortunately, the app can also crash even if you go to spin a second wheel while the first is still spinning.  And Josh Highland's link is good but he has static content in his picker whereas two of my components keep reloading their content based on the selection of the first / second components, hence my crash problem :o(  I might be able to do something with that - (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component he mentions though - and if it works I will accept your answer.