# UIPickerView crashes app when user is spinning components at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, uipickerview

I've got really unbearable issue with UIPickerView. There're 2 components: first one with food categories, and second with foods inside each category. I've got proper arrays with foods, which looks like:

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *leftPickerDataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *vegetablesDataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *eggsDataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pastaDataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *riceDataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *meatDataSource;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
...
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize foodPicker;

@synthesize leftPickerDataSource;
@synthesize vegetablesDataSource;
@synthesize eggsDataSource;
@synthesize pastaDataSource;
@synthesize riceDataSource;
@synthesize meatDataSource;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.leftPickerDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Vegetables", @"Eggs", @"Pasta", @"Rice", @"Meat", nil];
    self.vegetablesDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Potatoes", @"Broad bean", @"Beans", @"Broccoli", @"Cabbage", @"Cauliflower", @"Corn", nil];
    self.eggsDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Soft-boiled", @"Hard-boiled", nil];
    self.pastaDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Pasta", @"Spaghetti", nil];
    self.riceDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"White", @"Brown", @"Black", @"Red", nil];
    self.meatDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sausages", @"Crabs", @"Lobsters", @"Shrimps", nil];
}
```

I believe arrays ain't the problem, but when I spin two components of picker at the same time, the app usually crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1...).

Here goes my UIPickerView:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        // Left picker
        return [leftPickerDataSource count];
        //[foodPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        // Right picker
        NSInteger sRow = [foodPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
        if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Vegetables"])
            return [vegetablesDataSource count];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Eggs"])
            return [eggsDataSource count];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Pasta"])
            return [pastaDataSource count];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Rice"])
            return [riceDataSource count];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Meat"])
            return [meatDataSource count];
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        // Left picker
        return [leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else {
        // Right picker
        NSInteger sRow = [foodPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
        if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Vegetables"])
            return [vegetablesDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Eggs"])
            return [eggsDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Pasta"])
            return [pastaDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Rice"])
            return [riceDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual:@"Meat"])
            return [meatDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0)
        [foodPicker reloadComponent:1];
}
```

Can't find anything suspicious here too. Have no idea why, but spinning the wheels crashes the app. I looked for answers at SO, but nothing helps :/

Have you any idea what's the matter?

Comment: Try to put the exception breakpoint. This will point you to the line in your code that is responsible for crash.

Comment: I think you are not reloading picker for all componnnents.

Comment: I think your problem is that the second component's title depends on which row is selected in the first component. While the first component is spinning, I'm guessing that the selectedRowInComponent:0 is undefined or nil so none of your else-if statements returns true.

Comment: @PratyushaTerli First one breakpoint is for `else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:sRow] isEqual: eggsCat]) return [eggsDataSource objectAtIndex:row];`, but still don't know why. It looks ok for me.

Comment: @preetam That's not the issue. Reloading all components doesn't help at all unfortunately. In fact it's unneeded to reload them all.

Comment: Is spinning single component at a time working?

Comment: @rdelmar It makes sense. I tried simple get rid of `if` statement in last `else` in both `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` and `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:`, but that's inadequately. Have you any idea what can be really helpful in this case?

Comment: try the answer specified in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198413/custom-uipickerview-limit-user-to-spinning-one-wheel-at-a-time.when you try to spin two components at same time which are dependent then u will get a crash

Comment: @PratyushaTerli I saw this thread and I think my `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` works in the same way. I've got only two components, so I need only `if (component == 0) { [pickerView reloadComponent:1]; }` and it's in my code already.

Comment: try adding `[foodPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES]` after `[foodPicker reloadComponent:1]` line in your `didSelectRow:`

Comment: @PratyushaTerli Unfortunately nothing has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I was wrong in my supposition -- the selected row is not undefined or nil, but it's changing rapidly while you spin. The problem is that the number you return in numberOfRowsInComponent depends on where the spinning dial is when that method runs, but by the time titleForRow runs, the first component is on a different row, and you're trying to access rows that don't exist. To fix it, you should define a property sRow, assign it a value in numberOfRowsInComponent, and then use that same value (don't re-assign like you're doing now) in titleForRow, rather than getting a new value.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger sRow;

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        // Left picker
        return [leftPickerDataSource count];
        //[foodPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        // Right picker
        self.sRow = [foodPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
        if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Vegetables"])
            return [vegetablesDataSource count];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Eggs"])
            return [eggsDataSource count];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Pasta"])
            return [pastaDataSource count];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Rice"])
            return [riceDataSource count];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Meat"])
            return [meatDataSource count];
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        // Left picker
        return [leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else {
        // Right picker
        if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Vegetables"])
            return [vegetablesDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Eggs"])
            return [eggsDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Pasta"])
            return [pastaDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Rice"])
            return [riceDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
        else if ([[leftPickerDataSource objectAtIndex:self.sRow] isEqual:@"Meat"])
            return [meatDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! It looks like great improvement! I tried it and figured out it less problematical than original code. Unfortunately it still can crash with this error:

Comment: `MyApp(6862,0x3b39fb78) malloc: *** mmap(size=3841531904) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
MyApp(6862,0x3b39fb78) malloc: *** mmap(size=3841531904) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
2013-08-31 07:49:55.412 MyApp[6862:907] *** Assertion failure in -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableViewRowData.m:400`

Comment: @PiotrSochalewski, under what circumstance do you get this error? I copied and pasted your code, making only the change I showed in my answer. I haven't been able to make it crash.

Comment: @rdelmar Not crashing anymore I have copied your code and executed it

Comment: Two fingers: left on first component and right on second one. When I move them simultaneously maximally up it makes this error.

Comment: @PiotrSochalewski, did you copy my code? Do you have other code in this class that you're not showing? I've done the same testing (on an iPhone 4), spinning both wheels rapidly for a minute straight, I haven't gotten it to crash.

Comment: Just false alarm. I don't know why but I lost (probably cut it) fragment of code with last array, so when I move to the bottom it was empty. Your solution works flawlessly! Thank you very very much. Hope it helps other too, because I found some similar threads here, but there weren't such great answer!

Comment: this answer still crashesh

Comment: @rdelmar May I have one more question connected with this picker view? I know the easiest way (and it works, but not in this case, where component no. 1 has to be reloaded) to programmatically select row for UIPIckerView is `selectRow:inComponent:animated:`. Unfortunately `[foodPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];` doesn't reload items in component no. 1. I have tried manually `reloadComponent`, but it didn't help. Have you any idea?

Comment: @PiotrSochalewski, you need to put a slight delay in after selecting the row in component 0. So, in viewDidLoad, I put: [foodPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(reload1) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01]; then I added the method, reload1, and did the reloadComponent in there: -(void)reload1 {
    [foodPicker reloadComponent:1];
}

Comment: This technique worked great for me in a 3 component picker where the 2nd depends on data in the first and the third depends on data in the second. Otherwise it would crash when moving columns at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want both to scroll together, what is the purpose of making two components?**

**If your first component values are depend on zeroth component then
ideally it should not make any sense to scroll multiple component together.**

You can make multiple pickers having single component.

**Update**:
One more option,you can implement logic such a way that until user selects zeroth component app will not show first component,called dependent uipickerview.
Have a look at this question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077470/question-regarding-implementation-of-multi-component-dependent-uipickerview?lq=1)

Comment: Exactly I don't want to scroll them together, but noticed that serious bug accidentally. As far as you know wheel usually doesn't stop immediately, and then when you try to move second one wheel it's going to crash. Inconvenient I guess.
In addition single picker with several components in iOS 6 and older looks just more elegant than two pickers.

Comment: @PiotrSochalewski:wheels dont stop immediately but untill it gets stop further data will not be considered correctly.

Comment: So do you think that there is no other possibility to make it work correctly than separate pickers?